# Leaflet sidebar-v2 - not floating display on mobile

Tags: html, css, leaflet, mapping

I don't want the sidebar to always fill the entire vertical side. I solved that by adjusting the height of the `.sidebar.collapsed`

However, when on a mobile device it still fills the entire side vertically and does not float over the map as on the desktop version. I assume this is not a bug but rather might be a simple fix in the `@media` section. I am not sure where to adjust it.

I have not modified the sidebar code except for the above mention css edit, and a text decoration addition to the `.sidebar-pane` section.

```
.sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 2000; }
  .sidebar.collapsed {
    width: 40px; 
    height: 120px;}
  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    .sidebar {
      top: 10px;
      bottom: 10px;
      transition: width 500ms; } }
  @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
    .sidebar {
      width: 305px; } }
  @media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
    .sidebar {
      width: 390px; } }
  @media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .sidebar {
      width: 460px; } }

.sidebar-left {
  left: 0; }
  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    .sidebar-left {
      left: 10px; } }

.sidebar-right {
  right: 0; }
  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    .sidebar-right {
      right: 10px; } }

.sidebar-tabs {
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fff; }
  .sidebar-left .sidebar-tabs {
    left: 0; }
  .sidebar-right .sidebar-tabs {
    right: 0; }
  .sidebar-tabs, .sidebar-tabs > ul {
    position: absolute;
    width: 40px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none; }
    .sidebar-tabs > li, .sidebar-tabs > ul > li {
      width: 100%;
      height: 40px;
      color: #333;
      font-size: 12pt;
      overflow: hidden;
      transition: all 80ms; }
      .sidebar-tabs > li:hover, .sidebar-tabs > ul > li:hover {
        color: #000;
        background-color: #eee; }
      .sidebar-tabs > li.active, .sidebar-tabs > ul > li.active {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #0074d9; }
      .sidebar-tabs > li.disabled, .sidebar-tabs > ul > li.disabled {
        color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.4); }
        .sidebar-tabs > li.disabled:hover, .sidebar-tabs > ul > li.disabled:hover {
          background: transparent; }
        .sidebar-tabs > li.disabled > a, .sidebar-tabs > ul > li.disabled > a {
          cursor: default; }
      .sidebar-tabs > li > a, .sidebar-tabs > ul > li > a {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        line-height: 40px;
        color: inherit;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-align: center; 
        list-style-type: none; 
        padding-top: 10;
        padding-right: 0;
        padding-left: 0;
        padding-bottom: 0;
        }
  .sidebar-tabs > ul + ul {
    bottom: 0; }

.sidebar-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95);
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto; 
  text-decoration: none; }
  .sidebar-left .sidebar-content {
    left: 40px;
    right: 0; 
    text-decoration: none; }
  .sidebar-right .sidebar-content {
    left: 0;
    right: 40px; }
  .sidebar.collapsed > .sidebar-content {
    overflow-y: hidden; }


.sidebar-pane {
  display: none;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px 20px; 
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif; }
  .sidebar-pane.active {
    display: block; 
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif; }
  @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
    .sidebar-pane {
      min-width: 265px; } }
  @media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
    .sidebar-pane {
      min-width: 350px; } }
  @media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .sidebar-pane {
      min-width: 420px; } }

        .sidebar-pane > li.disabled > a, .sidebar-pane > ul > li.disabled > a {
          text-decoration: none;
          color: inherit; 
          font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif; }
      .sidebar-pane > li > a, .sidebar-pane > ul > li > a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: inherit;
        font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif; }

.sidebar-header {
  margin: -10px -20px 0;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 14.4pt;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #0074d9; }
  .sidebar-right .sidebar-header {
    padding-left: 40px; }

.sidebar-close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer; }
  .sidebar-left .sidebar-close {
    right: 0; }
  .sidebar-right .sidebar-close {
    left: 0; }

.sidebar-left ~ .sidebar-map {
  margin-left: 40px; }
  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    .sidebar-left ~ .sidebar-map {
      margin-left: 0; } }

.sidebar-right ~ .sidebar-map {
  margin-right: 40px; }
  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    .sidebar-right ~ .sidebar-map {
      margin-right: 0; } }

.sidebar {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65); }
  .sidebar.leaflet-touch {
    box-shadow: none;
    border-right: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); }
  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    .sidebar {
      border-radius: 4px; }
      .sidebar.leaflet-touch {
        border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); } }

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .sidebar-left ~ .sidebar-map .leaflet-left {
    transition: left 500ms; } }

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  .sidebar-left ~ .sidebar-map .leaflet-left {
    left: 315px; } }

@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
  .sidebar-left ~ .sidebar-map .leaflet-left {
    left: 400px; } }

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .sidebar-left ~ .sidebar-map .leaflet-left {
    left: 470px; } }

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .sidebar-left.collapsed ~ .sidebar-map .leaflet-left {
    left: 50px; } }

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .sidebar-right ~ .sidebar-map .leaflet-right {
    transition: right 500ms; } }

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  .sidebar-right ~ .sidebar-map .leaflet-right {
    right: 315px; } }

@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
  .sidebar-right ~ .sidebar-map .leaflet-right {
    right: 400px; } }

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .sidebar-right ~ .sidebar-map .leaflet-right {
    right: 470px; } }

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .sidebar-right.collapsed ~ .sidebar-map .leaflet-right {
    right: 50px; } }
```